# Java happend-before in synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization, monitor, synchronized, java-memory-model

I need some help understanding the Java memory model.The following is a gerneric example to grasp the basic concept:

Image I have an object instance called `Shared` and two threads `A` and `B`. Furthermore there is some kind of `Queue` with a synchronized `put` and `take`.

Thread `A` modifies the `Shared`-instance **before** and **in** the `put` method.

Question 1: **All** changes from `A` are visible when `B` gets the `Shared`-object instance through the synchronized `take`-method?

Question 2: The memory cache is flushed (all changes on `Shared` are visible) as soon as `A` leaves the synchronized `put`-method. What exaclty happens if `wait()` is called in the `put`-method by `A`? Will `B` also see the changes done to `Shared` even though `A` hasn't yet exited the `synchronized`-method? Is the cache also flushed when calling `wait()`?

Comment: very confusing question. Perhaps some codesample. How does the queue change the passed object in the put method for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1**: Yes. Because both take() and put() are synchronized. So before B could execute take(), A should have left the synchronized block and leaving the synchronized block means flushing memory cache(memory fence/barrier).

**Answer 2**: Yes. Because when wait() is called, the thread has to surrender the lock, which will again cause memory flushing.

EDIT: I think what you are after is that whether **cache-write-to-memory** happens on exit of synchronized block or release of lock. The answer is **cache-write-to-memory happens on release of lock**.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first questions is Yes, because synchronization points (present in put and take) introduce implicit memory fences.

For the second question, it depends if A calls wait before or after the object is added to `Shared`. If it is before, then obviously there is no change to shared and so B has nothing new to see.

**Edit**: If A calls wait after, then the change is visible because you had to acquire a lock before adding and then release it when waiting which also introduces a fence.

So the answer is Yes in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, A first changes Shared and then calls wait(). It calls wait on the Queue-instance. I'm just not sure if calling wait counts as "exiting the synchronized block". Because the memory flush is only guranteed when exiting the synchronized block. Understand what I'm after? :-)

Answer (score 2):

> A hasn't yet exited the synchronized-method? Is the cache also flushed when calling wait()?

Quoting from [JSR 133 (Java Memory Model) FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) - [What does synchronization do?](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization) :

> After we exit a synchronized block, we release the monitor, which has the effect of flushing the cache to main memory, so that writes made by this thread can be visible to other threads. Before we can enter a synchronized block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main memory. We will then be able to see all of the writes made visible by the previous release.

It says that flushing the cache to memory happens when a monitor is released. Note that  while the monitor is released while exiting a synchronized block, it is also released while calling the wait method. So I'd expect the changes to be flushed on the #wait() call and to be picked up by the other thread provided it was waiting earlier on the same monitor.